# write data in json format to js file?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I am thinking of this idea:
1. Request data from server and write to javascript file in json format using C#
2. When the page loads, the page loads the js file and I can use the data using javascript?

is this a good or bad idea?
is there any example somewhere doing that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take into account:

- **Performance**, do you expect the dataset to be small enough to be managed by browsers? How complex are the relationships between your entities?
- **Security**, how will you secure the data to avoid malicious code execution?

Taking into account these concerns I'd recommend JSON for data interfaces.

Comment: it is only one table with 7 fields, as well as it will not contains that much data.
only authorized person can load the json, and it is read only.

Comment: If he outputs JSON, he should be fine security wise - as long as he makes sure user-data ends up properly escaped in strings, which, unless he's reinventing the JSON outputter wheel, should be done by whatever JSON library he's using.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript performance varies by browser, and can go downhill under load, but with that small of a dataset you shouldn't have to worry about that.

If you are using MVC, AJAX and JSON are very easy.

Answer (score 0):

My company does this occasionally when the page is meant to hold only static data. It looks something like this in a .aspx document:

```
var initialData = <asp:Literal runat="server" id="MyAwesomeLiteral" Text="null" />;

myObject.init(initialData);
```

This only works if you're confident that your data can't be manipulated to bad ends. If you have IDs, especially sequential ones, encrypt them.